# Jquery - On Click on div trigger ajax post and wont disable clicking afterwards

Tags: jquery, class, javascript

I have a simple div that i use to trigger an ajax post. I call the object by one of it's classes when it is clicked. When i submit and render the same object again i dont want it to be clickable so i remove the class from the object but it still is clicking even though in the dom it is gone. Any ideas how to prevent the object from being clicked again?

The Ajax post works fine just trying to figure out how to stop another click after the submit is complete.

Code:

HTML:

```
<div class="likeContent">
    <div class="bylineBox right likeThisLink" id="like-this-<?php echo get_comment_ID(); ?>">
         <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="likeThisContent">
             <span>
                 <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/like-icon.png" alt="Like" />
                 <?php if ($current_like_count[0] > 0) { echo $current_like_count[0];} else {echo 'Like';} ?>
             </span>
         </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS (Jquery function):

```
$('.likeThisLink').click(function(e) {
    var contentID = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[2];
    var siteURL = $('.siteURL').attr("id");
    var templateURL = $('.templateURL').attr("id");
    var processURL = siteURL + "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"
     $.post(processURL,{
      action: 'my_unique_action',
      content_id: contentID },  
      function(data) {  
        var currentLikeCount = $('.likeCount-' + contentID).attr("id").split("-")[1];
        var newLikeCount = parseInt(currentLikeCount) + 1;
        $('#like-this-'+contentID).fadeOut().html("<a><span><img src=\"" + templateURL + "/images/like-icon.png\" alt=\"Like\" />" + newLikeCount + "</span></a>").fadeIn();
        $('.likeCount-' + contentID).attr("id", "likeCountCurrent-" + newLikeCount);
        e.preventDefault();
      });  
     $(this).removeClass('likeThisLink')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `one` function for this like:

```
 $(".likeThisLink").one("click", function() {
 ....
});
```

The code will only execute once no matter how many times it is clicked. You can read up on it here http://api.jquery.com/one/

**EDIT** Alternatively you can unbind the click function like this:

```
$('.likeThisLink').unbind('click');
```

Comment: Will this still work if another button is clicked that triggers the same function? I will have many like buttons on one page that could be clicked

Comment: It will not. Each button will be capable of being clicked once and executing the request.

Comment: This will get attached to the element with the `likethislink` id only I think. Do you have a class for ALL the like links or does each have its own ID?

Comment: Sorry I just realized that it was a `class` and not an `ID`. I updated my answer.

Comment: This seems to work by adding the one function, i am going to go with this method, thanks

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use a global boolean to flag that the button has been clicked and the request made. If another click happens, you ignore the post request. Once the post request returns (either successfully or erroneously) you mark the flag back to its initial state.

Example:

```
var disabledButtons = {};
$('.class').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    if( disabledButtons[id] != true ) {
        disabledButtons[id] = true;
        $.ajax({
            success: function() {
                disabledButtons[id] = false;
            },
            error: function() {
                disabledButtons[id] = false;
            }
        });
    }
 });
```

Haven't tested it, but that's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would change how you're doing the bind:

```
$(document).on('click', '.likeThisLink', function(e) {
    var contentID = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[2];
    var siteURL = $('.siteURL').attr("id");
    var templateURL = $('.templateURL').attr("id");
    var processURL = siteURL + "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"
     $.post(processURL,{
      action: 'my_unique_action',
      content_id: contentID },  
      function(data) {  
        var currentLikeCount = $('.likeCount-' + contentID).attr("id").split("-")[1];
        var newLikeCount = parseInt(currentLikeCount) + 1;
        $('#like-this-'+contentID).fadeOut().html("<a><span><img src=\"" + templateURL + "/images/like-icon.png\" alt=\"Like\" />" + newLikeCount + "</span></a>").fadeIn();
        $('.likeCount-' + contentID).attr("id", "likeCountCurrent-" + newLikeCount);
        e.preventDefault();
      });  
     $(this).removeClass('likeThisLink')
});
```

This way it won't be a static binding, but instead will continue to use the selector (which will allow you to manage it via changing the class).